# Sample vs Apparent vs True error rates of a confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, error

Consider a machine learning program which produces a classifier that works perfectly correctly on 1,000 training examples. When subsequently applied to 100 different, randomly selected examples the results are:

```
               Actual Class
                  P   N 
Classifier P:    10   5
Results    N:    15  70
```

What would be the sample error rate, apparent error rate, and estimated true error rate? And what are their differences?